# How to Affect Adjacent Element with CSS Hover

Tags: html, css, opacity

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="flexi-overlay">
        <a id="flexi-overlay-image-link-container" href="#" class="popup image-link"?>
            <img src="image.jpg" />
        </a>            
        <span id="flexi-overlay-text-container">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="flexi-link" id="title-1">Modern Duets</span>
                <span class="flexi-link" id="title-2"><em>Flexi Compilation</em></span>
                <span class="flexi-link" id="title-3"><strong>**New**</strong></span>
            </a>
        </span>
</div>
```

I want to lower the opacity of the image in the link on top when the link on the bottom of the page is hovered over. I tried doing the following, but it hasn't worked.

```
#flexi-overlay-text-container + #flexi-overlay-image-link-container {
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:.6;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that because you are trying to match a previous sibling. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector

Comment: Agree with @4lbertoC. You could place the image after the text link in your html, and then postition it on top of the page by means of css, to be positioned on top of the page, [something in this direction](http://jsfiddle.net/xpFAf/1/)

Comment: Something like this? [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rtz3w/)

Comment: @Mr_Green jQuery is not exactly a CSS :hover solution, but anyway a good suggestion ^_^ I just updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rtz3w/2/) to do more explicitely what OP wants.

Comment: @MartinTurjak I think this is still broken.. Not working as expected on Chrome.

Comment: @Mr_Green I am not sure what you are talking about is broken? In your solution (as well as in your solution with my update with id selectors in jquery) the [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) works fine for me in Chrome 26.

Comment: @MartinTurjak lol I have chrome 26 but it is not working.. (I don't know why, maybe problem with my PC). I just shared idea that it could be done like this without testing it. :) (that's why I added weird borders).

Comment: @Mr_Green Well, I think it is not a bad alternative, if someone is willing to use jQuery, hence my +1 on your comment above ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can make `flexi-overlay-image-link-container` the child of `flexi-overlay-text-container` and change css like:

```
#flexi-overlay-text-container:hover>#flexi-overlay-image-link-container {
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:.6;
}
#flexi-overlay-image-link-container:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/ew227/2/)